# Tensor product of Frobenius algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

In proving the fact that the tensor product of any two finite-dimensional Frobenius algebras $R$ and $S$ over the same field $k$, it is usually defined a $k$-bilinear pairing $E: W×W→k$ where $W=R⊗_kS$ as follows:

$E(∑_ir_i⊗s_i,∑_jt_j⊗u_j)=∑_{i,j}B(r_i,t_j )C(s_i,u_j)$,

where $B:R×R→k$ and $C:S×S→k$ are the non-singular $k$-bilinear maps with the associativity property.

In an algebra text it is said that the matrix of $E$ is the Kronecker product of those of $B$ and $C$ with respect to suitable bases, and so $E$ is nonsingular.

> My questions are:
>   (1) what is the matrix of a pairing?
>   (2) what do one means by the Kronecker product with respect to some basis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are finitely dimensional $K$-vector spaces of the same dimension and $f:V\times W\to K$ is a bilinear pairing, then the matrix of $f$ in the bases $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$, respectively $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ of $V$, respectively $W$ is given by $(f(x_i,y_j))_{1\le i,j\le n}$.

In your case $E(r_i\otimes s_j,r_k\otimes s_l)=B(r_i,r_k)C(s_j,s_l)$ and this matrix is nothing but the [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of $B$ with $C$. If $B$ and $C$ are non-singular, then $E$ is also non-singular since $\det E=(\det B)^q(\det C)^p$, where $p=\dim_K R$ and $q=\dim_K S$.